# How to use SQL Lab with Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm new to Redshift and I'm going a bit nuts trying to figure out how to query Amazon Redshift using SQL Lab. No matter what query I try, even a simple `select * from table_name limit 10;`

I get the error: "Failed to start remote query on worker. Tell your administrator to verify the availability of the message queue."

I tried to use Queues http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-executing-queries.html with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late now probably... But let's have the answer for the sake of people who googled to this place (like I did) and had no luck getting the answer.

Try disabling `Allow Run Async` as this option requires a Celery Worker setup - something I don't currently know about :). In any case, this resolved the issue.